# Magento Login Blank Screen No Error, Resolved only when sessions cleaned

Tags: php, mysql, magento, session

Magento 1.7.0.2

When visiting my root domain, everything runs as it should, all items show up and everything moves pretty smoothly.

When I try to login to a front end account, I get a completely blank page, with no errors, and no error log recordings. The page turns white when encountering the login post function

SITE.com/customer/account/loginPost/

At this point, every page on the site is completely blank.

The only way to resolve this whiteout, that I have found thus far, is to delete the related session files in var/sessions.

-I have tried Raising my PHP MEM limit,

-I have also tried adding developer mode coding to the index.php page to no avail.

-I have not modified my theme or any other files in quite a long time.

-I Have not added any new modules or plugins recently.

Can anyone help me by providing some methods with which I might be able to pull more information out of this error, so that I could get a better idea of what is causing the issue?

Thank you all for reading.

Comment: I have also created a brand new account, which can login and logout fine. However when I try to login with the existing account I still receive the same error. Perhaps this is a database issue?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to seemingly one account now.

I can only replicate the error on... my personal account, new accounts, test accounts, and other accounts I have created in the past work fine, but not mine.

Its not much of a problem if it is localized just to my account, but it still doesn't make any sense as to why it would be occuring. I do know that my account is the first one in the database, perhaps theres some incremental error or something?

Comment: Probably, an easy thing to do is copy your user's row in the database to a new row with a different ID, change the username, and email, and try logging in again.

Comment: Also, consider an upgrade to your magento installation: ver 1.8.0.0 - Added Sept. 25, 2013

Comment: Im not currently able to upgrade to Magento 1.8.0.0 due to reliance on incompatible programs. I am in the process of developing a new site, however I think I would rather wait for 1.8.0.1 to address all of the initial errors. But I wont hold my breath on that update. Let me investigate the user row idea you pointed out. Thank you very much for your comments sir.

Comment: I would however like to be able to diagnose and correctly fix this, without patching it over and avoiding the issue by posting the details to a new row. I think where theres smoke, theres fire, and there has to be something else going on here.

Comment: I will have to look into the code for that version...

Comment: Evaluation of the account in question through PHP my admin shows that is seems to be correctly configured and incremented.

Comment: I think this is a bug, even I had same issue where one of my account had become unusable though I would face issues only when I tried to checkout